# Equivalent of never(mock) in JMockit

Tags: jmockit

I'm migrating some test cases from JMock to JMockit. It's been a pleasant journey so far but there's one feature from JMock that I'm not able to find in JMockit (version 0.999.17)

I want to check that a mock is never called (any method).

With JMock, all I needed is the following in my Expectations block:

```
never(mock)
```

Is it feasible somehow with JMockit?

**EDIT:**

I might have found a solution but it's not very explicit.
If I put any method of this mock with `times =0` in my Expectations block then this mock becomes strict and I believe any method called would trigger an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try an empty *full* verification block, it should verify that no invocations occurred on any given mocks:

```
@Test
public void someTest(@Mocked SomeType mock)
{
    // Record expectations on other mocked types...

    // Exercise the tested code...

    new FullVerifications(mock) {};
}
```